# Getting the class Type of the selected node in a tree

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

i created a tree , in my case every level of the tree represents a type of objects so i have( level 1:Family ,level 2:TestList,Level 3:Test) , i want to get the type of the selected node in the tree :

```
if (selectedNode != null) {
      if (selectedNode instanceof Family) {
         pFamily = (Family)selectedNode;
          new DefaultTreeNode(newSuite.getName(),selectedNode); 
      } else if (selectedNode instanceof TestList) {
         pFamily = (((TestList)selectedNode).getFamilyFromModel());
          new DefaultTreeNode(newSuite.getName(),selectedNode.getParent()); 
      } else if (selectedNode instanceof Test) {
         pFamily = (((Test)selectedNode).getTestListFromModel().getFamilyFromModel());
          new DefaultTreeNode(newSuite.getName(),selectedNode.getParent().getParent()); 
      }
```

but every time i'm getting this value DefaultTreeNode i when i run :

```
system.out.println( selectedNode.getClass());
```

(the class type of the selected node )

Here's how i add a node of type Family in the tree :

```
List <Family> familyList =DataLoader.getCurrentProject().getFamilyListFromModel();
    for (int i=0 ;i<familyList.size();i++)
    {   family=familyList.get(i);
        familyNode= new DefaultTreeNode(family.getName(), testPlanNode);  }
```

so is it possible to do this?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have just to make this change :

```
 <p:treeNode  value="#{node}">
      <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
 </p:treeNode>
```

and to retrieve the selected node in the form of object do this :

```
 Family family =(Family)(selectedNode.getData());
```

Comment: There is no way that works if your node's data is a `String`. How are you going to cast that to `Family`?

Comment: @RinaldoPJr what i wrote is to complete your own answer so node data is not a string it's an object got it ?

Comment: for more information you can see this basic example : (http://javaevangelist.blogspot.com/2012/07/custom-primefaces-tree-example.html)

Answer (score 3):

That happens because your `selectedNode` is indeed a `DefaultTreeNode`.

What you want is the **data** your node is holding, and you can do that by calling `selectedNode.getData()`. The retrieved value is the one you should be comparing.

---

The way you are constructing your nodes will **always** give you a `String`, and that's simply because you **are** telling it to hold a `String`, that is the name of the family: `new DefaultTreeNode(family.getName(), testPlanNode)`

Instead, you should be doing: `new DefaultTreeNode(family, testPlanNode)`, and on the view:

```
<p:tree var="node">
    <p:treeNode>
        <h:outputText value="#{node.name}"/>
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

And make sure any kind of object the node is holding has the `getName()` method. An Interface would be nice.

---

Make sure you read [PrimeFaces documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html) and use it as our best friend.

Comment: i tried it like that :  public void testFn(ActionEvent actionEvent){
    System.out.println(selectedNode.getData().getClass());
   }                                                                   but it gives  me class java.lang.String.
 So there's a problem when adding the node just have look in my edit i added the code of adding new node in the tree . Many thanks

Comment: i'm getting this error value="#{node.name}": Property 'name' not found on type java.lang.String here's the code                                                                    <p:tree id="testPlanetree"
        value="#{projectTestManagementMB.root}" var="node"
        selectionMode="single"
        selection="#{projectTestManagementMB.selectedNode}"
         dynamic="true">
 <h:outputText value="#{node.name}"/>

Comment: @user1657164 That's because you are still initializing the `DefaultTreeNode` with `family.getName()`. Read my answer carefully, I showed how to initialize it with the whole `family` object: `new DefaultTreeNode(family, testPlanNode)`.

Comment: yes this's what i did , but the problem with the  value="#{projectTestManagementMB.root}" var="node" the node var type is TreeNode

Comment: @user1657164 Yes, it is supposed to work like that. Maybe you could supply your current code for Tree creation, xhtml and bean.